# Algorithm Identification [ String & Dictionary ]

Tags: algorithms, strings

I recently heard of an interview question:

```
 Given a string and a dictionary. Break the string into meaningful words
```

and I remember solving this before with dynamic programming fairly quickly (maybe O(n) time? ) in one of my old algorithm classes but I can not remember the name of the algorithm. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instincts are on the money though as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466972/how-to-split-a-string-into-words-ex-stringintowords-string-into-words) Stack Overflow question, tries (prefix trees) are also a valid solution. The process is called "Word Segmentation".